# HTML 5 coding in blackberry

Tags: html, blackberry, html5-video

I am starting to develop and Mobile application in blackberry for 5, 6 and 7 BB OS.

I got to know that HTML 5 is new stuff which i can use in my BB apps.

I m trying to show HTML 5 video, what type of code i need to write to handle that from webservice.

Please let me know any type of coding related to HTML 5 in blackberry mobile application.
THanx in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

I use this to perform HTML5, http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html, I have also found that Blackberry only supports a few video formats.